# How do I get an image to display on a page when the path for the image is in a MySql database?

Tags: php

Here is the 'id' and (path) 'name' in the MySql table called "upload":

```
 rec_id | name
--------+------------------------------------------------------
      1 | C:\Apache Tomcat 5.0.28\htdocs\ajax\images\blob1.jpg
      2 | C:\Apache Tomcat 5.0.28\htdocs\ajax\images\blob3.jpg
      3 | C:\Apache Tomcat 5.0.28\htdocs\ajax\images\blob2.jpg
```

Comment: where is the php file making the mysql call located on your server?

Comment: It's generally better to just store the relative path (e.g. `blob1.jpg`). Then this will work: `<img src="/images/<?=$name?>" />` or `<img src="<?=IMAGE_PATH.$name?>" />`.

Comment: @konforce But then he won't be able to access the files on the filesystem level any more, e.g. to check whether they still exist. He'll have to guess the filesystem path then, which is worse than having to guess the web path IMO.

Comment: @Pekka Either way, he has to know what the filesystem path is. If stored as-is, he'll need to chop it off. If left off, he'll need to add it back on (when doing local file operations). If everything is rooted to the same base folder, then I find it easier to store the relative path... especially if I ever have to move the physical location.

Answer (score 1):

Get the image ID from `$_GET[]`, set the `Content-type` with [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), then use [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the image path into a web URL.

1. Fetch the desired image path from the table
2. Find out what your web root is (I'm guessing it's `C:\Apache Tomcat 5.0.28\htdocs`) and put it e.g. into a constant `define("WEBROOT", "C:\....");` You could auto-detect the web root using [**DOCUMENT_ROOT**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) but setting it manually is more reliable.
3. Cut off the web root from the path `str_replace(WEBROOT, "", $image_path);`
4. Voilá! You have a relative URL to your image that you can output: `<img src='/ajax/images/blob1.jpg'>`

Comment: This assumes that all the pathnames in the database are somwhere under the document root.

Comment: @Ignacio Yes, I am assuming that is the case looking at the paths he shows. We'll see whether this is the case here. But my comment to your question was incorrect, I thought he was explicitly looking to *link* to the images, which he was not. Sorry.

Comment: // I tried this in PHP:
$string = '';
$pic = '';

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $string .= "<b>".$row->name."</b> - ";
    $string .= $row->phone." - </a>";
    $string .= $row->picpath."</a>";
    $pic    .= "<img src='picpath'>";
    $string .= "<br/>\n";
  }

}else{
  $string = "No matches!";
} 

echo $string;
echo $pic;
----------------and this gives me:

Mark Hanson - 314-346-5856 - http://transeeq.com/kearney/images/bolts.jpg
//--but the image did not come up

Comment: You forgot the `$` in `picpath`.

Comment: Here is the syntax that worked for me:

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $string .= "<b>".$row->name."</b> - ";
    $string .= $row->phone." - </a>";
    $string .= $row->title." - </a>";
    $string .= $row->picpath."</a>";
    //$pic      .= "<img src='picpath' width='250' height='70' alt='some pic' />";
    //$thumbImage = '<img src="'.$row->picpath.'" title="' . 'ddd' . '" />';
    $thumbImage = '<img src="'.$row->picpath.'" title="' . '$row->title' . '" />';
    $string .= "<br/>\n";
  }

}else{
  $string = "No matches!";
}